# Getting the bytes of a `str` at compile-time

Tags: string, rust, constants

Is there any way to get the bytes of a `str` at compile-time in Rust? Specifically, I want to create a `const` like:

```rust
const FOO_BYTES: [u8; 3] = [70, 79, 79];
```

but I want to write out a string literal instead of writing the encoded bytes by hand.

Using plain `str::as_bytes` doesn't work because it returns a slice (`&[u8]`). I tried using `try_into`, but that gave a different error:

> calls in constants are limited to constant functions, tuple structs and tuple variants

because `try_into` is not a `const fn`. What should I do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the prefix `b` to create a [byte string literal](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/tokens.html#literals):

```
const FOO_BYTES: &[u8; 3] = b"FOO";
```

If you don't want a reference, just deref `*` it:

```
const FOO_BYTES: [u8; 3] = *b"FOO";
```

Comment: Wow, somehow I didn't think of using `b"..."`. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

I'm still curious if there's a way to do this, but I think in the end using a slice is probably fine:

```rust
const FOO_BYTES: &[u8] = b"FOO";
```

**EDIT:** You can use `b"..."` as [@kmdreko suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64949710/11588505).